# Need to scrape a data from a website using xpath and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Hello guys**

[website link](https://tipsters.asianbookie.com/index.cfm?player=Mitya68&ID=297754&sortleague=1#playersopenbets)

The story is that he tried to scrape a table named "Open Bets", but unfortunately the table has no class or id, i used beautifulsoup to scrape the table and i used XPath to detect the table but nothing happened as you see in the picture below:

[image]

I tried to scrape the data from the table and detect named like the column named "Team A" Vs "Team B"
the point is I show the data like that

```
print(Player1," vs ",Player2)
print("Odds ",odds)
print("Rate ",rate)
print("stake ",stake)
```

I think you will understand what I trying to do here
this is the table below:
[image]

I tried to contact the admin of the website to add classes or something to code source but nothing.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://tipsters.asianbookie.com/index.cfm?player=Mitya68&ID=297754')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
ID = tree.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[7]')
print(ID)
```

this is the code I used, please if someone can help with that will be great =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use `pandas`. Here is how you do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://tipsters.asianbookie.com/index.cfm?player=Mitya68&ID=297754&sortleague=1#playersopenbets&tz=5.5').text

dfs = pd.read_html(r)

df = dfs[141]

df.columns = df.iloc[0]

df = df.drop(0)

df['Bet Placed ≡'] = [value.split('.')[-1] for value in df['Bet Placed ≡']]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0   Bet Placed ≡              Team A  ...   Rate         Pending Status
1    9 hours ago         Real Madrid  ...  1.975            pending ?-?
2    9 hours ago   Red Bull Salzburg  ...  1.875            pending ?-?
3    9 hours ago                Ajax  ...   2.00            pending ?-?
4    9 hours ago       Bayern Munich  ...   2.00            pending ?-?
5    9 hours ago       Bayern Munich  ...   1.85            pending ?-?
6    9 hours ago         Inter Milan  ...  1.875            pending ?-?
7    9 hours ago     Manchester City  ...   1.95            pending ?-?
8    9 hours ago         Midtjylland  ...  1.875            pending ?-?
9    9 hours ago  Olympiakos Piraeus  ...   1.95            pending ?-?
10   9 hours ago          Hamburg SV  ...  1.925            pending ?-?
11   9 hours ago         Vissel Kobe  ...  1.925   Lost(-25,000) FT 1-3
12   9 hours ago     Shonan Bellmare  ...  1.825   Won½(+10,313) FT 0-0
13   9 hours ago    Yokohama Marinos  ...  2.025   Won½(+12,812) FT 2-1
14   9 hours ago        RKC Waalwijk  ...  1.875            pending ?-?
15   9 hours ago            Espanyol  ...  2.075  lose(-25,000) 29' 1-0

[15 rows x 7 columns]
```

You can also get these values as separate lists by adding these lines to your code:

```
team_a = list(df['Team A'])
team_b = list(df['Team B'])
rate = list(df['Rate'])
stake = list(df['Stake'])
```

If you want to print them in the format that you have mentioned, add these lines to your code:

```
final_lst = zip(team_a,team_b,stake,rate)

for teamA,teamB,stakee,ratee in final_lst:
    print(f"{teamA} vs {teamB} - Stake: {stakee}, Rate: {ratee}")
```

Output:

```
Real Madrid vs Shaktar Donetsk - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.975
Red Bull Salzburg vs Lokomotiv Moscow - Stake: 100000.00, Rate: 1.875
Ajax vs Liverpool - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 2.00
Bayern Munich vs Atl. Madrid - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 2.00
Bayern Munich vs Atl. Madrid - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.85
Inter Milan vs Monchengladbach - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.875
Manchester City vs Porto - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.95
Midtjylland vs Atalanta - Stake: 100000.00, Rate: 1.875
Olympiakos Piraeus vs Marseille - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.95
Hamburg SV vs Erzgebirge Aue - Stake: 100000.00, Rate: 1.925
Vissel Kobe vs Kashima Antlers - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.925
Shonan Bellmare vs Sagan Tosu - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.825
Yokohama Marinos vs Nagoya - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 2.025
RKC Waalwijk vs PEC Zwolle - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 1.875
Espanyol vs Mirandes - Stake: 25000.00, Rate: 2.075
```

Comment: that's amazing! i just want to know how to detect players names and the rate & stake and transfer them to a variable

Comment: Player names? Is the player name Mitya68 in this case?

Comment: as you see on the table there is a column "Team A" and "Team B" the point is to scrap the players names on team a and add them to a variable and scrap team b and add to a variable and scrap the rate of each player for example "Vissel Kobe" Vs "Kashima Antlers " - stake : " 25,000.00" - rate "1.925"

Comment: i want to scrap like that ... scrap data, add them to a variable and display the result like that : var(player1), "vs" ,var(player2) - stake : var(stake) - rate : var(rate)